# How do you specify a where clause on data returned from a .Include in an Entity Framework query?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Given the following database table hierarchy:

```
Region
------
RegionId
RegionName

Country
-------
CountryId
RegionId
CountryName

Destination
-----------
DestinationId
CountryId
DestinationName

Venue
-----
VenueId
DestinationId
VenueName
```

I have the following Entity Framework query:

```
var result = from region in context.Region.Include("Country.Destination.Venue") 
select region
```

which will return all rows from all tables (outer join)

Is it possible to introduce a where clause so that only rows where the venue is not null are included (or use an inner join) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this.  It should return the results you are looking for: only regions that have a corresponding venue.

```
    var result = from region in context.Region.Include(Country.Destination.Venue)
                 let v = (from ctry in region.Country
                         join dest in context.Destination
                         on ctry.CountryId
                         equals dest.CountryId
                         into destGroup
                         from dests in destGroup
                         join ven in context.Venue
                         on dests.DestinationId
                         equals ven.DestinationId
                         into venGroup
                         select ctry).Any()
                 where v == true
                 select region;
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this however it brings back all regions in the case that there is an associated Country and Destination but no associated Venue.

Comment: Ok.  You might be right.  I tested this on a sample app here but I only had three tables to play with, not four.  I hope this shows an example of what you might try though.